# Wordpress WooCommerce Grid / List toggle: How to trigger a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

The "WooCommerce Grid / List toggle"-plugin toggles the view of a list of products in WooCommerce. The last selection is stored in a cookie.

HTML-page contains:

```
<nav class="gridlist-toggle">
  <a href="#" id="grid" title="gridview">&#8862; <span>gridview</span></a>
  <a href="#" id="list" title="listview">&#8863; <span>listview</span></a>
</nav>
<ul class="products">
  <li class=" ...
```

Javascript function is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#grid').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery('#list').removeClass('active');
        jQuery.cookie('gridcookie','grid', { path: '/' });
        jQuery('ul.products').fadeOut(300, function() {
            jQuery(this).addClass('grid').removeClass('list').fadeIn(300);
        });
        return false;
    });

    jQuery('#list').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery('#grid').removeClass('active');
        jQuery.cookie('gridcookie','list', { path: '/' });
        jQuery('ul.products').fadeOut(300, function() {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('grid').addClass('list').fadeIn(300);
        });
        return false;
    });

    if (jQuery.cookie('gridcookie')) {
        jQuery('ul.products, #gridlist-toggle').addClass(jQuery.cookie('gridcookie'));
    }

    if (jQuery.cookie('gridcookie') == 'grid') {
        jQuery('.gridlist-toggle #grid').addClass('active');
        jQuery('.gridlist-toggle #list').removeClass('active');
    }

    if (jQuery.cookie('gridcookie') == 'list') {
        jQuery('.gridlist-toggle #list').addClass('active');
        jQuery('.gridlist-toggle #grid').removeClass('active');
    }

    jQuery('#gridlist-toggle a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

How do I always get listview on the main shop page and always gridview on category pages disregarding the user's choice?

Answer (score 0):

Use WordPress Conditional Tags.

Use Php to set the cookie to a default. Something like...

```
<?php if (is_page(id)) { 
        $defaultView = 'list';
     } 
      else {
        $defaultView = 'grid'; 
     }
        setcookie("gridcookie", $defaultView);
      ?>
```

Replace `id` with the page id for your main shop page. Or use one of the other options http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: it identifies the page alright, however there will only 1 option given. I could live with it. Problem remains: the last selected value is read from the cookie. How could I send a "listview-button was clicked"?

Comment: Sorry I read your question as wanting to only give the user the choice of "listview" on the main page. But you are saying you want both views available to the user, just no matter which view they click, you want the Javascript to set the cookie as "listview?" Essentially  you want it to "lie" even if they choose gridview, correct? ;)

Comment: What I really need is a pre-selection every time a page is called. Listview is the pre-selection on the main shop page and gridview is the pre-selection on category pages. I hope this clears up the request.

Comment: So when the main shop page loads, you want the listview to show by default and gridview by default on the category pages?  So what if a user loads the main page which defaults to listview, switches it to gridview, then navigates away, if they return to the main page again, do you want it to remain on gridview, or default back to listview?

Comment: every time go back to pre-selection

Comment: Ok I hope I am understanding correctly now what you are wanting. I changed the php code in my script entirely with the exception of the WordPress conditional "is_page" bit. Now php is setting the cookie to a default value every time the page loads.